# windows server 2003 feature install is asking for amd64 folder and evntagnt.dll file

Tags: windows-server-2003

I wanted to turn on snmp feature on windows 2003 R2 Standard X64 Edition Service Pack 2.

My problem is that turning on that feature requires a cd labeled: Service Pack 2 CD-ROM

I Downloaded it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=6905

But feature installation is looking for this folder:

d:\amd64

and it's looking for a file evntagnt.dll

I can't find that file in the iso and neither the folder.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the needed files here:
 Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition x64 with SP2 Trial (64-bit x64)
disk1: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/D/F9DA93F8-2814-4B9B-A6A1-EA9B6B7E8BD6/X13-05825.img
﻿disk2: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/D/F9DA93F8-2814-4B9B-A6A1-EA9B6B7E8BD6/X13-05774.img

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: Windows Server 2003 has been end-of-life and out of support for several years now. You really shouldn't be using it.

I find that file (`amd64\evntagnt.dll`) available on Disc 1 of the non-Service-Pack-2 CD/DVD. You'll need your original ISOs or CDs or DVDs. The Service Pack 2 ISO that you refer to -- `w2k3sp2_3959_usa_x64fre_spcd.iso` -- is just the cumulative service pack, so it only includes the changes and updates between the base Windows Server 2003 install and Service Pack 2. If `evntagnt.dll` was not part of that cumulative change set, it won't be on the ISO.

The filename of the Disc 1 ISO (at least of my copy of it) is `BRMSXVOL_EN.ISO`. I can't find that available for download from Microsoft, nor can I find any non-SP2 downloads of Windows Server 2003. (This is one of the many reasons to migrate off of unsupported versions.)

If you don't have your original CDs, DVDs, or ISOs, you might be able to find someone with a copy of `evntagnt.dll`, but I'd be cautious of accepting it from an untrusted source.